# Deceleration to terminal velocity under constant force

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, drag

I am modeling an object under a force $F$ that diminishes with distance but is considered constant at small time intervals. I am also incorporating a drag force $D$ that is opposite the direction of $F$ and dependent on velocity squared.  The net acceleration can be written as:

$$F-D=ma$$

As $D$ is velocity dependent, we can write a differential equation for velocity. $C$ is the coeffecient of drag, $A$ is the area, and $\rho$ is the air pressure.

$$\dfrac{\Delta v}{\Delta t} + \dfrac{CA\rho}{2m}v^2 = \dfrac{F}{m}$$

Setting acceleration $\dfrac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ to zero, we find can find terminal velocity.

$$v^2_{term} = \dfrac{2F}{CA\rho}$$

Another solution that got me this far indicates that we should rewrite the differential equation.  I myself am unsure of how to make this transformation.

$$\dfrac{1}{1-v^2/v^2_{term}}dv = \dfrac{F}{m}dt$$

Taking the integrals of both sides is indicated next.

$$\tanh^{-1}(v/v_{term}) = \dfrac{F}{mv_{term}}t + C$$

Setting $t$ to zero gives $C$ equal to $\tanh^{-1}(v_{0}/v_{term})$, and we can solve for $v_{t}$.

$$v_{t} = v_{term} \tanh(\frac{F}{mv_{term}}t + \tanh^{-1}(v_{0}/v_{term}))$$

Each term of this equation makes sense to me, as the equation of $tanh$ approximates the change in velocity towards terminal velocity, velocity increases toward terminal velocity faster under higher force, and initial velocity independently shifts the curve to the left.  My model shows a smooth reduction in acceleration as velocity approaches terminal velocity asymptotically for each time step.

My problem arises as such: because the force $F$ is distance dependent, there will come a time step where $v_{0}$ is greater than $v_{term}$, which is outside the bounds of the $tanh^{-1}$.  I am looking for an equation of motion for the approach of terminal velocity from a higher speed.

I deeply suspect it will take the form of $v_{t} = v_{term} \coth(something + \coth^{-1}(v_{0}/v_{term}))$, but I've been unable to find $coth$ on any integral lists, so I'm not certain how to get there.

Comment: I believe your misunderstanding  stems from the fact that you believe $v_{term}$ is constant it is not because F varies as distance varies well so tou need to take in to account the varying $v_{term}$

Comment: This problem could easily be described by a constant force and a sudden shift in terminal velocity, such as the object entering a new medium with a new density, eg. vacuum into atmosphere.  In any case, I'm looking for the solution of an object under constant force with an initial velocity greater than terminal velocity.